# Can't use the same proj name after deleting a project from Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

First I used sample_app as proj name, then I found something's wrong so I deleted the "sample_app" folder directly from my Mac. But when I create a new proj also named "sample_app", Rubymine got stuck -- I can't use generate command, it showed "processing" all the time.

I don't know if my way deleting proj is wrong or maybe there are other support files outside the proj folder I didn't delete. Finally I compromised, used other name and it works fine.

But I still wanna know why and how to fix the problem if I want to use same name?

Comment: restart mac solved everything. (I always put it sleep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your ruby mine stores the name in internal cache memory.

You can clear project list from:

> File > Reopen Project > Clear List

[image]

Comment: just clear list doesn't work. But, it turns out restart my mac is the right option.

Answer (score 0):

Try restart rubymine and give an other name